# url encoded characters in href not being decoded on click

Tags: html, urlencode

I have a href in my html like so:

```
<a title="Test" href="/website/reviews/index%23vehicle">Test review</a>
```

I expect the browser to decode the `%23` to `#` but its not doing so.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of encoding is so that you can use characters (such as `#`) **without** the browser doing what it would normally do with them.

If you want the browser to react to the `#` character then use the `#` character - don't encode it